# Spacing & Outlook IOS App signature

Tags: html, ios, outlook

I've recently tried using a HTML signature in the Outlook app for IOS and everything displays correctly but for some reason an extra line is inserted between each line of text. Can't seem to work out why, or whether there is issues with code / if I can implement anything to stop the extra line the Outlook app seems necessary.

```
<p style="font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; line-height: 12px; color: #1f497d; margin-bottom: 10px;">&nbsp;</p>
<p style="font-family: Helvectica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; line-height: 12px; color: #1f497d; ">Kind regards,&nbsp;</p>
<p>
<br /> <span style="color: #00b0f0; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px;"><strong>Full Name</strong></span>
<br /> <span style="color: #1f497d; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px"><strong>Company Name</strong></span></p>
<p><span style="color: #1f497d; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px">Direct: <span style="color: #e36c0a;">0207 201 <strong>1234</strong></span></span>
<br /><span style="color: #1f497d; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px"> Email: <a style="color: #1f497d;" href="mailto:email@email.co.uk">email@email.co.uk</a></span>
<br /><span style="color: #1f497d; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px"> Web: <a style="color: #1f497d;" href="http://www.website.co.uk/">www.website.co.uk</a></span></p>
<p style="font-size: 0px; line-height: 0; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;">&nbsp;</p>
```

[image: Image showing signature in email]

Any suggestions greatly appreciated, sending me mad!

Comment: Have you tried it without the line breaks? Outlook may have extra spacing for paragraph elements.

Comment: worked like a charm, thank you!